# Which is the best way to display combobox on a cell if a condition is verified?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

So here is my problem: I have to build a grid on my view (it can be a datagrid or a gridview, i have no particular preference). I know the number of columns, but i have to build the row dinamically. The problem is that there are some rows that must display a combobox on the third column if the datatype of the data inside the first column is different from "string", otherways they have a simple textbox. I know that there is a control named "template selector" which can do stuff like this, but since i never used it, i wonder if this is the best way to approach my problem.

Comment: In my experience, comboboxes in datagrids quickly become finicky. In any case, one possible solution would be to bind the visibility of the combobox (through a `BooleanToVisibilityConverter`) to a property whose `bool` getter just returns `!(itemInFirstColumn is string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following up on the comment, if you are willing to use `ItemsControl` in place of your grid, one way to achieve the behavior in question is as follows:

View:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label Width="150" Content="{Binding FirstProperty}"/>
                    <ComboBox Width="150"
                              Visibility="{Binding HasCombobox, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

Code-behind + view-model:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel();
    }
}

public class MainWindowViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        MyItems = new List<DisplayableItem>
        {
            new DisplayableItem { FirstProperty = "Some string" },
            new DisplayableItem { FirstProperty = 60 },
            new DisplayableItem { FirstProperty = "Also a string" },
        };
    }

    public IEnumerable<DisplayableItem> MyItems { get; }
}

public class DisplayableItem
{
    public object FirstProperty { get; set; }
    public bool HasCombobox => !(FirstProperty is string);
}
```

Comment: This approach is not bad at all. Just one question, if i bind the selection of the combobx to my ViewModel, do i have any problem with the OneWay Mode of the binding of the ItemControl?

Comment: Not anything that you will not still be able to get around; I think it will take a few more details on what you want to do to be able to tell what the most elegant approach is.

Comment: I took my time to test your solution, and it is very cloose to satisfy my need. I have one proble left before starting to customize this solution. Is there a way to have different item source for the combobox based on the datatype of FirstProperty?

Comment: A low-key solution would be to Let the bound `ItemsSource` itself return the relevant collection after checking `FirstProperty`. This places the selection logic in the view-model rather than the view, which may clash with the semantics of the application, depending a bit on what kind of data you are dealing with. If it makes more sense to have the logic entirely within the view, you may be able to set up what you want with triggers(?)

Comment: I'm building a wizard and at this point, i have to build the final screen that is a sum of every previous part. So it's fine to place the logic in the view model, since the choice of the combobox it's a part of my output. Thank you again for your help

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing any details about what you are trying to do, you could for example use a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a `CellTemplateSelector`/`CellEditingTemplateSelector`.

The following sample code should give you the idea:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dg">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dtA">...</DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="dtB">...</DataTemplate>
        <local:Selector x:Key="selector" TemplateA="{StaticResource dtA}" TemplateB="{StaticResource dtA}" />
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding A}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding B}" />
        <DataGridTemplateColumn CellEditingTemplateSelector="{StaticResource selector}">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding C}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

---

```
public class Selector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate TemplateA { get; set; }
    public DataTemplate TemplateB { get; set; }

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        System.Data.DataRowView dr = item as DataRowView;
        //return TemplateA or TemplateB based on your logic

        return base.SelectTemplate(item, container);
    }
}
```